# Indefinite Integral: $\int sec^{n}x dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How do I show that

$$\int \sec^{n}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{n-1}\sec^{n-2}(x)\tan(x) + \frac{n-2}{n-1}\int \sec^{n-2}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Inductively! ${}$

Comment: Also, integration by parts?

Comment: You can always check an integration formula by differentiating both sides, and seeing whether the difference simplifies to $0$.

Comment: Note: you'd better exclude the case $n=1$, where the right side is undefined.

Comment: See  http://calc101.com/deriving_reduction.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peel off two factors of secant:
$$
    \sec^n x = \sec^{n-2} x \cdot\sec^2 x
$$
Now integrate by parts with $u=\sec^{n-2} x$ and $dv = \sec^2 x\,dx$.  Rearrange making use of the formula
$$
    \tan^2 x = \sec^2 x - 1
$$

Comment: I started like that, but got stuck half way and i assumed it was wrong. Well at least, i started right. Thanks!